# Understanding RDS billing

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-billing

I had mistakenly launched a db.r6g.large PostgreSQL instance and deleted it instantly while under Free Tier. I also deleted all the snapshots as well. Yet, I see daily increase in the bill by a few cents. Anyone knows what to do there?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did AWS tell you when you asked them?

Comment: AFAIK AWS does not speak with Free Tier users. You have to pay $29/mo for at least [developer support tier](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/plans/developers/).

Comment: Billing support is free, don't need to pay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db.r6g.large` database would not qualify for the Free Tier.

Therefore, the bill is showing a charge for the instance that you launched.

Since you turned off the instance and deleted the snapshots, the charges should not increment any more.